# while inserting the data from one table to another table can we write a query like except column name?

Tags: mysql

I'm using Mysql alpha-community version-6-0-11. I want the clarification to write the insert into query, is it possible to write a query like :

```
insert into tablename_with_same_columns select * from tablename_with_same_columns except ID (because here ID is the auto-increment column)
```

This is the correct query :

```
insert into tablename_with_same_columns(col,clo1,col2,col3,col4) select from col,clo1,col2,col3,col4 tablename_with_same_columns
```

I know the above query is correct but in my scenario my table contains 100+ column names (we need to write all the column names for the only reason is to avoid the "Auto-increment column")

So I want the clarification that is, can we achieve the query with out write all column name?
(Because, like this I have a multiple table 100+ columns )

I'm new to mysql

give me your best solution for this.
(sorry for my bad English)

Comment: wha using an alpha version at all and you can only avoid it with dynamic sql and the information:_Schema and running over it

Comment: In short, no. And 100 columns is sometimes suggestive of deeper problems

Comment: Ok I understood, there is no possibility to write a query like that and thank you for your valuable solution...